# javascript: change color of a single word into a <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple div tag like this

```
    <div id="mydiv"> text inside the div </div>
```

I need a script that when i click on a single word of "mydiv" turns that word into red color (and save the word into a variable). I could surround every word in a span but i'm looking for a more clean solution. Is it possible?
Sorry for my poor english.

so far I've tried nothing. I'm still thinking about a solution. I could easily solve the problem sorrounding every word in a span but before writing that i want to be sure that a more easy solution doesn't exist. I'm sorry

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You can't, you need to put them in span.

Comment: Surprise!! He already has one upvote for not showing what he has done so far and a guide to how to do that?? Can we please encourage people who actually tried something? not everyone who asks questions?

Comment: @JoulinRouge Upadted the Answer with JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

**JavaScript : UPADTE**

[JSFiddle : DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zgy9szw0/3/)

```js
function mynew() {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var contents = myDiv.innerHTML.split(" ");
    var modText = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
        modText += '<span>' + contents[i] + '</span> ';
    }
    myDiv.innerHTML = modText;

    window.onclick = myFunction;

    function myFunction(e) {
        e.target.className = "change";
        /* STORED IN "SELECTED" VARIABLE */     
        var selected = e.target.innerHTML;
        alert('Selected: ' + selected);
    }
}
```

```css
span.change {
    color: red;
}
span {
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<body onload="mynew();">
    <div id="mydiv" class="new">text inside the div</div>
  </body>
```

**JQuery : Previous Post**

```js
$(function() {
  var contents = $('#mydiv').text().split(' '),
    modText = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    modText += '<span>' + contents[i] + '</span> ';
  }

  $('#mydiv').html(modText);

  $('#mydiv').click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).toggleClass('change');
    /* STORING EVERY WORD IN VARIABLE NAMED 'SELECTED' */
    var selected = [];
    $('span.change').each(function() {
      selected.push($(this).text());
    });
    alert('Selected: ' + selected.join(','));
  });
});
```

```css
span.change {
  color: red;
}
span {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">text inside the div</div>
```

> **Note:** If you do not want to toggle the change of color, then remove `toggleClass()` and add `addClass`.
>
> **Compatibility :** Works on Webkit and Mozilla and IE9+

Comment: I didnt see jquery tag

Comment: @RoyiNamir I really missed this. I don't know why i didn't see this. Thank You... Updated the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Voila,

```
function change (id,text) {

    var yazi = $('#'+id).text();
    var adet = yazi.split(' ');

    $('#'+id).html('');

    for (i=0,v=adet.length;i<v;i++) {

        if(adet[i]==text) {
            $('#'+id).append("<span style=\"color:#F00\">"+ adet[i]+"<span> ")
        } else {
            $('#'+id).append(adet[i]+" ");
        }
    }

}
```

call

```
change('mydiv','inside');
```

Comment: misunderstood fellas.